# Sparql get individuals from top class only

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I feel like this has an obvious answer I'm missing, but here's the problem:

I have an ontology which has a class 'Class_N1', with a subclass 'Class_N2', which has a subclass 'Class_N3', which has a subclass 'Class_N4'

When I run this query:

```
SELECT ?entity
WHERE {
    ?entity rdf:type :Class_N1
}
```

I get individuals from the top class ('Class_N1') and from its subclass and respective subclasses.

Is there anyway to get results which belong only in the top/super class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have inferencing enabled. There are three options to disable inferencing:

1. Choose the "No inference" ruleset when creating your repository ([screenshot](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/devhub/inference.html#standard-rule-sets)).
2. Uncheck the `>>`-like icon in the query editor ([screenshots](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/querying-data.html)).
3. Use GraphDB [pseudo-graphs](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/query-behaviour.html#how-to-query-explicit-and-implicit-statements):

   ```sql
   SELECT ?entity
   FROM <http://www.ontotext.com/explicit>
   WHERE { ?entity rdf:type :Class_N1 }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was starting to suspect it was an inference problem but had no knowledge of the pseudograph thing. It will come in handy